# Saving Bitmap to MemoryStream

Tags: c#, bitmap, memorystream

I am trying to save a bitmap to a `MemoryStream` and then convert it to string. But the problem is, I am having an error that says the line `img.Save(m, img.RawFormat);` cannot be `null`. [The error is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7ZnR.png)

The bitmap is from a fingerprint scan, that I converted to image. Now I want to convert its data to a string, by using MemoryStream. This is for the fingerprint data to be saved in the database. I don't know where I went wrong. You can find my code below:

```
        Bitmap bitmap;
        bitmap = ConvertSampleToBitmap(Sample);
        Bitmap img = new Bitmap(bitmap, fingerprint.Size);
        this.Invoke(new Function(delegate () {
            fingerprint.Image = img;   // fit the image into the picture box
        }));
        string ping;
        using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
        {
            img.Save(m, img.RawFormat);
            ping = m.ToString();
        }
```

I hope for an accurate answer that can pin point the major error and what parts of the code should I change. 
Though any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: hmmm; nothing *should* be `null` there - neither `m` nor `img` should be `null` here - are you sure that's the line that is throwing? Note, however, that `m.ToString()` isn't going to give you what you want. The data will be binary - what kind of string are you expecting here? would hex (base-16) or base-64 be useful here?

Comment: Here is the error that it throws, sir 
`System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: encoder'`

and base-64 string is actually what I need

Comment: for base-64: `ping = Convert.ToBase64String(m.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)m.Length);` - so; for the other bit - if you step through line by line, is the `'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: encoder'` coming *from the `Save` line*? I just want to be really sure, because that seems odd.

Comment: I actually wonder whether this is actually a thread affinity problem; meaning: I wonder if the `Save` needs to be *inside* the `this.Invoke` (everything in the `this.Invoke` will happen on the UI thread)

Comment: yes sir. The error points to that save line and highlights `img`

Comment: See msdn for example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.save?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting; what happens here is:

```
public void Save(Stream stream, ImageFormat format)
{
    if (format == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("format");
    }
    ImageCodecInfo encoder = format.FindEncoder();
    this.Save(stream, encoder, null);
}
```

with the inner `Save` doing this check:

```
public void Save(Stream stream, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
{
    if (stream == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("stream");
    }
    if (encoder == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("encoder");
    }
```

so; we can assume that `format.FindEncoder();` is returning `null` here. As it happens, this is indeed the default if there is no matching codec:

```
internal ImageCodecInfo FindEncoder()
{
    foreach (ImageCodecInfo info in ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders())
    {
        if (info.FormatID.Equals(this.guid))
        {
            return info;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

So basically, it isn't clear, but the problem is: there is no encoder found for the image format that you're using. Try saving as a well-known format, not necessarily the one that it loaded from. Maybe use `ImageFormat.Png` and save it as a png?

```
img.Save(m, ImageFormat.Png);
```

and as already mentioned in the comments, to get base-64 of that, you'll need:

```
ping = Convert.ToBase64String(m.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)m.Length);
```

Comment: It can now read the fingerprint without the error, sir! Thank you for that!
But the new problem is that it won't show its string conversion.

I put the `Save` line inside the `Invoke` as you mentioned earlier and tried to show the string conversion of the bitmap in a MessageBox,but nothing is happening and the app only prompts the fingerprint image. Maybe you can help me figure this out as well?
`

Comment: I placed the `Save` line inside the `Invoke Function` and saved the bitmap in a well-known format. Now, it can already scan and show the fingerprint to a PictureBox and the error is already gone, sir! Thanks to that :)
But the string conversion is not working. I tried to put it in a `MessageBox` but nothing is happening. Maybe you can also help me figure it out? I'm new to C# so I'm really lost, sorry. Here's the code for you to understand it clearly:

Comment: `Bitmap bitmap;
            bitmap = ConvertSampleToBitmap(Sample);
            Bitmap img = new Bitmap(bitmap, fingerprint.Size);
            this.Invoke(new Function(delegate () {
                fingerprint.Image = img;
                string ping;
                using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    img.Save(m, ImageFormat.Bmp);
                    ping = Convert.ToBase64String(m.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)m.Length);
                    MessageBox.Show(ping);
                }
            }));`

Comment: @GhoennWoods I don't know without more context, and I've just downed tools for the day - probably won't be able to help you today

Comment: Oh okay. Though thanks for the help sir! It solved the first problem. :) Very much appreciated!